# Twitter API user timeline extraction in Node.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, twitter-oauth

I currently use [twit](https://github.com/ttezel/twit) node.js module and while it works very well I'm having one problem.

I want to be able to extract the Tweets made by an authorized user of my app. When I authorize in Twitter using twit module I send the following data:

```
var T = new Twit({
    consumer_key:         'xxxx'
    , consumer_secret:      'xxxx'
    , access_token:         'xxxx'
    , access_token_secret:  'xxxx'
});
```

Suppose I authorize that user through passport module or something like that - which data would I need to replace above to get the result I want?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

login to twitter, and go to dev.twitter.com and find the link "manage your apps" it will redirect you to apps.twitter.com, there you will find "create a new app" button, click on it and then fill the form. after creating an app go to the application you created and go to "keys and access tokens" tab and click on "Generate consumer key and secret" now copy "consumer key" "consumer secret" "access token" "access token secret" and put in your code.

if you are using passport authentication use the following code to get the logging user's "access token" and "access token secret"

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = "your consumer key got from above steps";
var TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = "your consumer key secret got from above steps ";

var UserSchema = new Schema({
provider: String,
uid: String,
name: String,
image: String,
token: String,
tokenSecret: String,
created: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

mongoose.connect(mongooseConnectionString);
mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

var User = mongoose.model('User');

passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
consumerKey: TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
consumerSecret: TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
callbackURL: twitterCallBackUrl
},
function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
User.findOne({uid: profile.id}, function(err, user) { //check if the user profile is already     present in the database
  if(user) { //if profilie is already present then do nothing
    done(null, user);
  } else {  //else save user profile and tokens in the database
    var user = new User();
    user.provider = "twitter";
    user.uid = profile.id;
    user.name = profile.displayName;
    user.image = profile._json.profile_image_url;
    user.token = token;
    user.tokenSecret = tokenSecret;
    user.save(function(err) {
      if(err) { throw err; }
      done(null, user);
     });
   }
  })
 }
));
```

I am supposing that you are already passport module so you can manage rest of the code yourself